# symfony access javascript in javascript for creating a worker

Tags: javascript, symfony, web

I am using Symfony and i want to access a javascript which is located in /web/js
to create a worker.

```
        var worker = new Worker('/web/js/recorderWorker.js');
```

Does someone knows how symfony links the javascripts, because this is not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow... Please read this, in order to better help I think you should start by asking a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
<script src="/js/recorderWorker.js"></script>
<script>
var worker = new Worker();
</script>
```

(The /web folder is usually document root, meaning you can ommit it.)

Good luck!

Comment: now i am confused, i tried to initialize the worker inside a javascript.

Comment: I assume you need to load the javascript first (thats what the <script src="xxx"></script> tag is for. And then in the second <script> tag you use it...

Comment: also, if you publish more of your source code, it would be alot easier to help you...